# How to start with/setup AMAZON EC2 ubuntu instance from a Win Terminal?

Tags: amazon-ec2, kickstart, tutorial

I am not able to find a startup easy guide to start with Amzaon EC2, though went through various AWS Docs but every doc is linked to one another, is there any Doc that is complete in itself and not require a too techie person for the JOB done?

I am having windows terminal with me but would like to start with Ubuntu instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [PDF version](http://awsdocs.s3.amazonaws.com/EC2/latest/ec2-gsg.pdf) of [Amazon's EC2 docs](http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/ec2/) seem to hold all the info I would need to get started.
Windows terminal will not get you far, if you want to use Ubuntu, you will need an SSH client of some sort, [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) gets the JOB done

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the [Amazon Docs](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SettingUp_CommandLine.html) for the AMI Tools. They detail the steps for various approaches, including using a command line.

The [basic steps](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/LaunchingAndUsingInstances.html) you will go through are:

1. Setup the command line tools
2. Choose your AMI (ec2-describe-images)
3. Setup your key pair (and [setup PuTTY](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html) so you can SSH into the instance, you can import your key with ec2-import-keypair)
4. Setup your security group (the default group is called 'default'; use ec2-authorize to open ports)
5. Start the instance (ec2-run-instances)

If you are just starting with EC2, I might suggest using the AWS console (web interface) to simplify some of the above tasks - you will still need PuTTY and a key to do anything meaningful though.